# What is $\gcd(5^n+7^n, 5^m+7^m)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $m,n\in \mathbb N$, what is $\gcd(5^n+7^n, 5^m+7^m)$?

Since the case $m=n$ is trivial, we may assume $m>n$, hence by the Euclidean algorithm we get $m=nq+r$.
$$d=\gcd(5^n+7^n, 5^m+7^m) =(5^n+7^n, 5^m+7^m-5^{m-n}(5^n+7^n))$$
$$= (5^n+7^n,7^n(7^{m-n}-5^{m-n}))=(5^n+7^n,7^{m-n}-5^{m-n}).$$
Repeating this $q$ times we get $$d= (5^n+7^n,7^{r}-5^{r}) $$
What’s next ?

Comment: Have you looked at any example?  Maybe a pattern emerges.

Comment: Wait, in the duplicates $m,n$ coprime. What about here.

Comment: @Mike It gets much more complicated when they are not coprime. EG If $ 3 \mid m, n$, then $5^3 + 7^3 \mid \gcd$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Actually the noncoprime case *very easily*  reduces to the coprime case - see my answer in the linked dupe.